# WPF Simple Validation Question - setting custom ErrorContent

Tags: c#, wpf

If I have the following TextBox:

```
<TextBox Height="30" Width="300" Margin="10" Text="{Binding IntProperty, 
       NotifyOnValidationError=True}" Validation.Error="ContentPresenter_Error">
</TextBox>
```

And this in the codebehind:

```
private void ContentPresenter_Error(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e) {
   MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ErrorContent.ToString());
}
```

If I enter the letter "x" in the text box, the message that pops up is

> value 'x' could not be converted

Is there a way to customize this message?

Comment: Why not just put your own string in the MessageBox.Show();?

Comment: Because I might have many other textboxes, and it would be nice to have one validation error handler that just takes the error content of the newest validation error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I dislike answering my own question, but it appears the only way to do this is to implement a ValidationRule, like what's below (there may be some bugs in it):

```
public class BasicIntegerValidator : ValidationRule {       

    public string PropertyNameToDisplay { get; set; }
    public bool Nullable { get; set; }
    public bool AllowNegative { get; set; }

    string PropertyNameHelper { get { return PropertyNameToDisplay == null ? string.Empty : " for " + PropertyNameToDisplay; } }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo) {
        string textEntered = (string)value;
        int intOutput;
        double junkd;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textEntered))
            return Nullable ? new ValidationResult(true, null) : new ValidationResult(false, getMsgDisplay("Please enter a value"));

        if (!Int32.TryParse(textEntered, out intOutput))
            if (Double.TryParse(textEntered, out junkd))
                return new ValidationResult(false, getMsgDisplay("Please enter a whole number (no decimals)"));
            else
                return new ValidationResult(false, getMsgDisplay("Please enter a whole number"));
        else if (intOutput < 0 && !AllowNegative)
            return new ValidationResult(false, getNegativeNumberError());

        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }

    private string getNegativeNumberError() {
        return PropertyNameToDisplay == null ? "This property must be a positive, whole number" : PropertyNameToDisplay + " must be a positive, whole number";
    }

    private string getMsgDisplay(string messageBase) {
        return String.Format("{0}{1}", messageBase, PropertyNameHelper);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can probably accept your own answer: I searched quite some time but didn't find another solution than this..

Comment: So be it - at least until someone comes along with something better :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use ValidationRules.

For instance, in my case, when a user enters an invalid value into a decimal datagridtextcolumn, instead of the default message "Value could not be converted" I can override it with:

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column5" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Waste_perc}" Width="auto">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="Waste" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <myLib:DecimalRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

and here's the code for the DecimalRule:

```cs
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    decimal convertedDecimal;
    if (!decimal.TryParse((string)value, out convertedDecimal))
    {
        return new ValidationResult(false, "My Custom Message"));
    }
    else
    {
        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```